# Is it possible to call every mobile phone in a particular area at a time?

Tags: trope

I've seen this phenomenon in the movie *Eagle Eye*, *Sherlock Holmes* television episodes, and *The Lawnmower Man*.
Every mobile gets a call at a same time from the same guy in a particular area. Is this plausible from a technology standpoint?

Comment: Sherlock sends out "text blasts" (on the show Sherlock) which is a far cry from actually calling the numbers. Still, I think that's as close to calling a lot of people at once gets from a logistical, possible standpoint. It's a nice 'Trope, but isn't possible using today's known tech.

Comment: Short answer is "yes". Various governments have used area texting and blanket calling (of every mobile phone within a cell area) to warn people of floods and natural disasters. The technology is not only plausible but in use regularly.

This isn't a sci-fi question though...

http://uk.eonline.com/news/446487/amber-alert-text-message-startling-sound-causes-mass-surprise-confusion-and-tons-of-tweets

Answer (score 3):

Modern cell phone technology isn't designed to permit a broadcast to all phones simultaneously. There is no control room at Verizon or Deutsche Telecom where someone can press a button and "call all the phones".

However, there are few hard obstacles to this happening. An artificial intelligence might manage to bulldoze through some of the lower level protocols, and cause all cell phones registered with a particular tower to ring simultaneously. The tower is already periodically sending updates to the phones, and even with several hundred phones connected there is enough bandwidth to ring them (which is to say, this takes almost no bandwidth at all).

Comment: cell hacking technology...cool

Comment: As is mentioned in the comments to the original question, localized broadcast is commonly done emergency text alerts, for example. It wouldn't be technically difficult to initiate a conference call between all of the phones on a particular cell. As far as I know, something similar is used for "push to talk" features on mobile phones.